# How can I retrieve and display data from mysql database using php PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I retrieve and display data from mysql database  using php PDO ? 
Here is my code. I know how to do it using mysql_ function .
This is what I tried but it displays nothing so far .

```
 #query to display the users 
$select_all=("select * from tish_user
inner join tish_clientinfor on  tish_user.user_id = tish_clientinfor.user_id
inner join tish_images on  tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
inner join tish_security on  tish_user.user_id = tish_security.user_id");
$result = $con->query($select_all);
#if the statement is success full
if($result !== false ){
$cols = $result->columnCount();
#echo number of rows 
echo 'num rows'.$cols.'</br>';
#pass the result set 
foreach($result as $row){
echo  $row['username'].'</br>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the prepare, you need to execute.

Like this:

```
$all->execute();
```

After that, loop through results:

```
while( $row = $all->fetch() )
    print_r( $row );
```

You can additionally give `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to the fetch statement for the associative results.

```
while( $row = $all->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    print_r( $row );
```

Comment: great but i did not get no results

Comment: Your query is supposed to produce any? More context required.

Comment: Yes like lets print username from tish_user table or better we use echo I will understand better

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer

```
$sql = ("select * from user");
$result = $con->$query($sql);
#if the statement is success full
if ($result) !== false ){
$cols = $result->columnCount();
#echo number of rows 
echo 'num rows'.$cols.'</br>';
#pass the result set 
foreach($result as $row){
echo     $row['username'].'</br>';
}
```